# Can't install Nuget package "RestSharp"

Tags: c#, nuget, restsharp, openalpr

I have to install the RestSharp NuGet package. But everytime i try to, these error shows up:

Installing via Console:

[image: Installing via Console]

Or installing via the NuGet UI:

[image: Installing via UI]

I need RestSharp for openALPR API.

Thanks for reading my question and maybe even anwsering it!

With best regards 
Fabian Maurhart

Comment: I don't think that this is an error specific to the Package... looks like you could be running a buggy version of NuGet or have a broken cache, found this as a reference, maybe the hints will help, even if this is a bit older: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3078

Comment: Thanks very much!
The Link you provided solved my problem and i managed to install RestSharp!

Comment: Added as answer, if you want to accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that this is an error specific to the Package... looks like you could be running a buggy version of NuGet or have a broken cache, found [this](http://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3078) as a reference, maybe the hints will help, even if this is a bit older.

#### Excerpt

Downloads:

https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe (or check here: https://dist.nuget.org/index.html)

You can run this from anywhere using command prompt or powershell.

Then you can run the following commands:

```
nuget.exe locals -clear global-packages
nuget.exe locals -clear packages-cache
nuget.exe locals -clear http-cache
```

*Thanks [Seeker1437](https://github.com/Seeker1437)*